# Установка переменых среды в Linux, cвязанных с JNI

Tags: java, jni, переменные, c++, linux

Как установить переменную `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` в Linux равной `'pwd'` и что такое `pwd` ([JNI Example](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html))?

Comment: Не думаю, что это продуктивная идея.

Answer (score 1):

`pwd` -- команда `shell Print Working Directory`, выдаёт на `stdout` текущую директорию. В `bash/sh`

```
 exprot LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
```

В `bash` можете

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)
```